# Angular 6 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') error

Tags: angular, api, rxjs, httprequest

```
createToken() {
    this._tokenService
        .getAuth(this.userId, this.token)
        .subscribe(res => 
        {}, 
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    getAuth(upn, token) {
        var param = {
            Upn: upn,
            Token: token
        };

        console.log(param);
        
        return this._http.post(
            this.REST_API_ADDR + "auth", 
            param, 
            this.getAuthRequestHeader()
        );
    }

    getAuthRequestHeader() {
        console.log("header");

        const authHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
        });

        return { headers: authHeaders };
    }
```

Try a `getAuth` request to store the Token. The request does not call the API and throws an error.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
> at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.applyUpdate
> (http.js:199)
> at http.js:170
> at Array.forEach ()
> at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.init
> (http.js:170)
> at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.forEach
> (http.js:235)
> at Observable._subscribe (http.js:1435)
> at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe
> (Observable.js:42)
> at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
> (Observable.js:28)
> at MapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call
> (map.js:18)
> at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
> (Observable.js:23)

Could you please tell me what part to check when this error occurs?
Also, if you know the cause of the error and how to solve it, please let me know.

Comment: what is the value of "token" & "upn"

Answer (score 0):

The bug is described and resolved here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18743#issuecomment-367742057

Basically, your header has undefined/null value. You should check the header-option you passing to the request.